# Cannot understand a python code

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix, 2d

Q.Write a program which takes 2 digits, X,Y as input and generates a 2-
  dimensional array. The element value in the i-th row and j-th column of
  the array should be i*j.

A.

```
input_str = raw_input()
dimensions=[int(x) for x in input_str.split(',')]

rowNum=dimensions[0]
colNum=dimensions[1]
multilist = [[0 for col in range(colNum)] for row in range(rowNum)]
for row in range(rowNum):
  for col in range(colNum):
    multilist[row][col]= row*col
print multilist
```

I want to know what is the meaning of 0 in `multilist = [[0 for col in range(colNum)] for row in range(rowNum)]`

Comment: You are creating a list of lists filled with zeros,  did you try printing it?

Comment: ya.....i have to create a 2 Dimensional List......the only thing is that i didn't understand the meaning of putting a 0 in `multilist = [[0 for col in range(colNum)] for row in range(rowNum)]`

Comment: `0` is the value of the elements in the list.

Comment: You cannot index an empty list so the sublists are filled with zeros so `multilist[row][col]` will work and not create an IndexError, if you played around with the code it would be pretty obvious.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In list comprehension, first, call it, argument is the value that will be inserted at the current iteration position.
It may be anything, so it is zero here.

This translates literally to standard:

```
multilist = []
for i in range(rowNum):
    row = []
    for j in range(colNum):
        row.append(0)
    multilist.append(row)
```

As you read this code from bottom to top scope, so do you the list comprehension.

First "argument" of the outer list is:

```
[0 for j in range(colNum)]
```

While first "argument", therefore an item,  of the inner list is 0.

So, this inner list is repeated rowNum times in the outer one:

```
[ [inner_list] for i in range(colNum)]
```

There is a slightly better way of doing this:

```
multilist = [colNum*[0] for x in xrange(rowNum)]
```

Comment: WOW......!! thank you for breaking the complexity of the code to a simpler one......it is really easy to understand it in this way :) :)
Thank You :D

Comment: No needs for thanks. :D That is why I am on SO. Just to remind you, you do not need to initialize to zero if you want to have items defaulting to i*j. I'd also advise you to leave list comprehensions for later in Python. First learn Python well. They're handy but if you are not sure what you are doing you might end with a generator or some other unexpected result.